# pkg package does not include all files

Tags: javascript, package

I have `node.js` app. I installed `pkg` to create executable file that can be run on any platform. I use `pkg .` command for it. The problem is I have few `csv` files and `config.json` file where I store all of my settings. They are all in `/settings/` folder. The problem is that they are not included in the `pkg` package and I get error after trying to run it. I tried to add

```
 "assets": [
      "settings/*",
      "settings/**/*"
    ]
```

into `package.json` file but it didn't work. How can I add all files that are in the `/settings/` folder so they are also included in the executive file without any errors?